# In memory SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3

In a Symfony 2.3 project, where should I create the SQLite database, if I have set up to work **in-memory**, as a second entity manager:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                # ...
            sqliteinmemory:
                driver:   pdo_sqlite
                host:     
                port:     
                dbname:   
                user:     myuser
                password: mypassword
                path:     /db/mydb.db
                memory:   true
                charset:  UTF8
```

Comment: Another option would be to use an in-memory tempfs like `/run` to store the datbase.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the db path to the dbname attribute too.

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        ...
        dbname: /path/to/db/mydb.db
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to create the connection with different name as described in cookbook
 [here  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html)